# Perdi a codificação do projeto

Tags: eclipse

Eu instalei o eclipse no meu computador Windows e baixei meu projeto pra dar continuidade ao mesmo, não havia percebido antes, mas na tela que trabalho, quando fui me deparar com um erro percebi que os caracteres estavam assim:

```
@Size(max = 20, message = "MÃ¡ximo de 20 caracteres permitidos.")
```

Sendo que no notebook não está e nem no `github`. Isso aconteceu no meu computador, alguém sabe se isso é opção do `eclipse` para que eu possa corrigir?

Comment: Verifica o encode do arquivo. Eh possível que tenha mudado.altera pra utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você provavelmente precisa mudar as configurações de encoding do Workspace, segundo essa resposta aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22100912/3473971

Vá em

> Windows -> Preferences, then under General -> Workspace

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que resolva seu problema!

Comment: Obrigado, era isso.